# First character uppercase in date fields in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I have several calculated date fields in a Writer file. I want the date to be displayed with only the first character uppercase.
The dates are shown in Spanish full date.

I tried using paragraph and character style but I only get all characters uppercase, all characters lowercase, or every first character of each word uppercase.

What I want is:

**Martes 18 de enero de 2022.**

But what I'm getting is:

**martes 18 de enero de 2022.**

**MARTES 18 DE ENERO DE 2022.**

**Martes 18 De Enero De 2022.**

Is there a field modifier that can do this?
Is there a style option for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://help.libreoffice.org/3.3/Writer/Changing_the_Case_of_Text#:%7E:text=To%20Capitalize%20Text&text=Choose%20Format%20%2D%20Change%20Case%20%2D%20Uppercase,first%20letter%20of%20each%20word.), it's not possible to format the date style as per your need. What you are looking for is a customized date with only 1 letter in the capital but the ***date*** field isn't like a **String**. But I will continue to look for answers and will revert back if I get any.